# Linking error using mex

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, mex

I would like to mex a file using OSX 10.9 with Matlab 2012a. Command I am using to mex a file is the following:

```
mex -v -L/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/   -I/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.12/include/ -larmadillo -lgfortran armaMex_demo.cpp
```

File `armaMex_demp.cpp` depends on the library armadillo which is located at `/usr/include/armadillo`.  Here is how I understand the command I am using to compile the file:

- `-v` means verbose
- `-L/usr/include/` tell linker to search for libraries at `/usr/include/`
- `-I/usr/include/` tell compiler to search for libraries at `/usr/include/`
- `-I/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.12/include/` same as above
- `-larmadillo` tell liner to use library named `armadillo`

Unfortunately I cannot compile the file. Here is the output I get

```
-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $PREF_DIR)
FILE = /Users/Ivan/.matlab/R2012a/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    MATLAB                = /Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app
->    CC                    = llvm-gcc
->    CC flags:
     CFLAGS             = -fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -Dchar16_t=uint16_T -arch x86_64 -isysroot         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -fexceptions
     CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
     COPTIMFLAGS        = -O2 -DNDEBUG
     CLIBS              = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
     arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    CXX                   = llvm-g++
->    CXX flags:
     CXXFLAGS           = -fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -std=c++11
     CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
     CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O2 -DNDEBUG
     CXXLIBS            = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
     arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    FC                    = gfortran
->    FC flags:
     FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -m64 -fbackslash
     FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
     FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
     FLIBS              = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -L -lgfortran -L -lgfortranbegin
     arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    LD                    = llvm-gcc
->    Link flags:
     LDFLAGS            = -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map
     LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
     LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
     LDEXTENSION        = .mexmaci64
     arguments          =  -L/usr/include/ -larmadillo -lgfortran
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
     LDCXXFLAGS         = 
     LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
     LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
     LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
     arguments          =  -L/usr/include/ -larmadillo -lgfortran
----------------------------------------------------------------

-> llvm-g++ -c  -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.12/include/ -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/include -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -std=c++11  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O2 -DNDEBUG  "armaMex_demo.cpp"

-> llvm-gcc -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map -o  "armaMex_demo.mexmaci64"  armaMex_demo.o  -L/usr/include/ -larmadillo -lgfortran -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
```

ld: library not found for -larmadillo
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
mex: link of ' "armaMex_demo.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in run_demo (line 3)
mex -v -L/usr/include/  -I/usr/include/   -I/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.12/include/ -larmadillo -lgfortran
armaMex_demo.cpp

Can someone explain why I am getting the error?

**Edit 1:**

The following

```
mex -v   -I/usr/include/     -I/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.12/include/  armaMex_demo.cpp
```

worked. Can someone explain why the first failed but second did not ? I found it simply by trial and error.

Comment: Try putting the link-libraries last on the command line.

Comment: `-L/usr/include` is suspicious.  You're correct, `-I` is for "include" paths for the compiler.  And you're correct `-L` is for library paths for the linker.  But `/usr/include` is not where libraries live.  Where is the armadillo library?  Specify that path to -L.

Comment: Once I deleted it I was able to compile. The library `armadillo` is located at `/usr/include/armadillo`. What is the purpose of `-L` flag then?